# Advice 64GB RAM; close to 100Gb committed in typical use (no games): Is upgrading to a Mobo that can handle 128Gb Ram + buying more (=$200) warranted?

Tags: motherboard, memory

With 64GB of DDR4 3200 RAM I can go over 100Gb committed without noticeable slow down under Windows 11 Version (10.0.22621 Build 22621), though I have crashed it at some point. Knowing how much I can push it relates to my question, so feel free to weigh in.

Hardware is Ryzen 3200Gon a MSI B450-A PRO and all SSD drives, except the OS on a NVMe.

Software: Just 2 Bible programs, OpenOffice and LibreOffice (and many documents open), and 7 portable browsers (each for its own general purpose)  with multiple tab rows (mainly forums and research, no games). Typical CPU use: 9-13%

Upgrade would cost about $200 if I just add two more 32GB sticks of compatible RAM. Yet Windows rarely crashes due to memory, so I wonder if I can just set a limit on use rather than upgrading.

But please refrain from suggesting closing tabs: It is just more efficient for me to have a large utility truck, so to speak.

[image: Taskbar]

[image]

Comment: Something seems very, very wrong with your system if those programs are using 82 GB. I suspect one of your preferred programs has a memory leak or very poorly programmed by wasting memory. Note that "committed" memory does not mean the memory is being accessed, it just means a program has asked for a chunk to be reserved. Theoretically you could commit all of your memory without stressing the system if the programs just reserve the memory and do nothing with it. (Like if it was leaking!)

Comment: I think your Classic Shell or Open Shell addon for Windows is the memory leak culprit, there are lots of people reporting memory leaks in it and there is no acknowledgement from the developer that it was fixed yet.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but as for where all the RAM is used, well, I mentioned 7 browsers with multiple tab rows (hack),  which means about 19 identifiable tabs per row on my screen,  but I failed to mention that totals at least 400  tabs. And yes, that it the way I want to operate (and I usually go  many days before a reboot).

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/vZqthMTr/Proc-Explr.jpg

Comment: As for Ready Boost, not, not with a NvMe being where the page file is(https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07L6DKM8V/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) . And all the other drives are SSD's.  https://superuser.com/questions/1470826/can-readyboost-be-enabled-on-a-machine-with-an-ssd-in-windows-10

Comment: Seconding @Romen, that is an impressive amount of memory usage—I think something is wrong. Ultimately though, this will just come down to your usage: do *you* think that you need the extra RAM to handle the number of tabs you want? There's not really a performance cutoff or something we can go on really; as such, any of our answers will just be random opinions with no more basis than yours. If you want to edit the question with more concrete stuff for us to go off of, happy to take a look at reopening the question, but as written I don't think we can provide much.

Comment: From the process explorer screenshot it appears that LibreOffice was committing a whopping 27 GB with 5GB actually in use! I would suggest closing some documents, or maybe looking into breaking up big documents into multiple files to reduce memory usage.

Comment: I would like to use this comment box to report a "change, which is that I upgraded to 128GB, using matched modules, all is running fine thank God and I appreciate the helpful input.

Answer (score -1):

The MSI B450-A PRO has USB 3.1. Get a 64GB or 128GB USB 3.1 flash drive, try making use of the **Windows ReadyBoost** feature.

This could possibly be a free *upgrade* if you already have a relatively large enough USB flash drive on hand to try, otherwise $20 from as simple as from Amazon vs $200+ for new mobo and RAM seems worth a try.  I would opt for a name brand like a SanDiskc.

Comment: Sorry, how is this supposed to help the OP? All their drives are already SSDs; no USB stick is going to be faster than an SSD, so any caching would be useless.

Comment: it would help the OP by recognizing it's not about a *usb stick being faster than an ssd* like you were so quick to point out but rather that he said **I have crashed it at some point... feel free to weigh in*.  I weighed in and u seem to be fixated on down voting rather than recognize his problem is not enough ram+disk cache.  so find some way to increase ram+virtual_memory space.

Comment: And because I missed *using all SSD's* I'm curious why no one simply mentioned adjusting where windows virtual memory is located and increasing that size.  Just put it on another ssd rather than on C: which is a limited NVMe.  Then again if there's no space on other ssd's then attempting to use readyboost with a usb stick which is potentially a zero cost option is still worth trying if windows accepts it.

Comment: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-move-virtual-memory-different-drive-windows-10

Comment: or scrounge another ssd, add it to an open sata port on the mobo and use that instead of a usb stick.  but if you're all out of sata ports and all ssd's are used up, go buy a whole new mobo and ram at $200+ versus trying a usb stick and readyboost

Comment: I didn’t downvote, that’s someone else, please don’t make assumptions. In any case, ReadyBoost won’t increase page file size, it’s a separate technology intended for use as an SSD cache. Even without that, putting the pagefile on a slower USB stick instead of the internal drive is a bad idea—the pagefile is already not as fast as system RAM, and you really want to do do what you can to avoid making that worse. You’d be better off moving something else to an external drive and keeping the pagefile on the fastest drive.

Comment: Ultimately though a larger pagefile isn’t going to act as a good replacement for sufficient system memory, unless you want a system that chugs horribly; if the OP wants more open stuff, they’ll need more RAM. As a stopgap solution though, it’s something.